# Why doesn't Flickr love me?

Tags: flickr

I was going to ask why my upload never finished, but this was more interesting:

```
x-flickr-loves-you: 0
```

This is an actual HTTP header returned by the URL `https://s.yimg.com/pw/combo/1/3.11.0` during the "publishing" phase when uploading images. Could it be related to privacy- or ad-related add-ons breaking the uploader?

[I am a pro user](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/112831/why-doesnt-flickr-love-me#comment100183_112831), and I have never had any infractions or other guff in my account history.

Comment: what privacy and ad blocker do you use? Desc your setup

Comment: Are you a Flickr Pro user? I wonder if `x-flickr-loves-you` equals `1` for Pro users...

Comment: Probably only someone from Flickr can answer. Random, odd-ball HTTP response headers are fairly common.